# CakePHP - Is it possible to run a website at plugin level?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, web

here's the folder setup:

www.blog.com uses **app/plugins/blog/webroot** as root

www.gallery.com uses **app/plugins/gallery/webroot** as root

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No

A plugin's webroot, unless you've added an appropriate (and complex) index.php file yourself, will not "work" as a doc root.

### Define appropriate routes.

When you request `blog.com` - just define appropriate routes e.g.:

```
Router::connect('/', array(
    'plugin' => 'blog',
    'controller' => 'blog',
    'action' => 'index'
);

Router::connect('/*', array(
    'plugin' => 'blog',
    'controller' => 'blog',
    'action' => 'view'
);
```

If you want the same application to respond to both of your applications (generally speaking not a good idea) then you can use the `HTTP_HOST` to choose between loading one set of routes, or another:

```
<?php // routes.php file

if (env('HTTP_HOST') === 'blog.com') {
    require 'routes_blog.php';
} else {
    require 'routes_gallery.php';
}
```

It's not a good idea because it can easily cause problems such as cache confusion. A better idea is to simply treat each application separately whether they use the same code or not.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying the approach defined in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126587/share-controllers-models-and-views-in-multisite-cakephp-2-3-installation

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any folder on a server as a root folder, it just needs to be configured in your server's hosts file. If it's your own server and it is running apache you'll find it at:

> apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

You're in luck if your domain name and hosting is with the same company, as there should be a setting for what folder on the server is the root folder. That really depends on the company though and the level of service you've purchased. I'd check out their FAQs to be sure.

Comment: I guess my question should be  I used to use /blog/ to visit the blog plugin, if i point www.blog.com to the plugin webroot, I got a blank screen.